# Hide checkout fields when selecting other countries

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, code-snippets

I am not a developer and I don't know much about code so I'm struggling a bit with this.
I have a shop that ships mainly to Peru, but i want to offer shipping to other countries now. The problem I have is that there are more fields for shipping within Peru while for other countries those are not necessary so I would like to hide/remove those when any other country that isn't Peru is selected.

I tried using the code below while setting a flat rate (flat_rate:3) for all other countries. The following three fields would hide 'billing_id', 'billing_address_2' , 'billing_reference'. When changing countries automatically the shipping option would change to flat rate and the fields would hide, it was working yesterday but today it only works if i change the country and then refresh the site. I'm not sure if i'm doing something wrong, or if there's any other way I could do it. I am using Code Snippets to add the code.

```
/* This piece of code will hide fields for the chosen method.
.hide_pickup {
    display: none !important;
}
*/
 
// Hide Local Pickup shipping method
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'hide_local_pickup_method' );
function hide_local_pickup_method( $fields_pickup ) {
    // change below for the method
    $shipping_method_pickup ='flat_rate:3';
    // change below for the list of fields. Add (or delete) the field name you want (or don’t want) to use
    $hide_fields_pickup = array( 'billing_id', 'billing_address_2' , 'billing_reference' );
 
    $chosen_methods_pickup = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping_pickup = $chosen_methods_pickup[0];
 
    foreach($hide_fields_pickup as $field_pickup ) {
        if ($chosen_shipping_pickup == $shipping_method_pickup) {
            $fields_pickup['billing'][$field_pickup]['required'] = false;
            $fields_pickup['billing'][$field_pickup]['class'][] = 'hide_pickup';
        }
        $fields_pickup['billing'][$field_pickup]['class'][] = 'billing-dynamic_pickup';
    }
    return $fields_pickup;
}
// Local Pickup - hide fields
add_action( 'wp_head', 'local_pickup_fields', 999 );
function local_pickup_fields() {
    if (is_checkout()) :
    ?>
    <style>
        .hide_pickup {display: none!important;}
    </style>
    <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ) {
            if ( typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined' ) {
                return false;
            }
            $(document).on( 'change', '#shipping_method input[type="radio"]', function() {
                // change flat_rate:3 accordingly
            $('.billing-dynamic_pickup').toggleClass('hide_pickup', this.value == 'flat_rate:3');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Bhautik who told me to use updated_checkout, I am leaving here the code i am using and that works correctly for me!

```css
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'remove_peru_billing_checkout_fields');

function remove_peru_billing_checkout_fields($fields) {
$shipping_method ='flat_rate:3';
// 'flat_rate:3' shipping method can be changed.
global $woocommerce;
$chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
$chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

if ($chosen_shipping == $shipping_method) {
unset($fields['billing']['billing_id']); // IDs to hide
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_reference']);
}
return $fields;
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'billing_country_update_checkout', 50);
function billing_country_update_checkout() {
    if ( ! is_checkout() ) return;
    ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    let isRefreshPage = false;
    jQuery('form.checkout').on('change', 'select[name=billing_country]' ,function() {
        var val = jQuery( this ).val();
        if (val) {
            isRefreshPage = true;
        }
    });
     
    jQuery('body').on('updated_checkout', function(){
        if (isRefreshPage) {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
</script>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `updated_checkout` trigger that is called after the checkout update. try the below code.

```
// Hide Local Pickup shipping method
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'hide_local_pickup_method' );
function hide_local_pickup_method( $fields_pickup ) {
    // change below for the method
    $shipping_method_pickup ='flat_rate:3';
    // change below for the list of fields. Add (or delete) the field name you want (or don’t want) to use
    $hide_fields_pickup = array( 'billing_id', 'billing_address_2' , 'billing_reference' );
 
    $chosen_methods_pickup = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping_pickup = $chosen_methods_pickup[0];
 
    foreach($hide_fields_pickup as $field_pickup ) {
        if ($chosen_shipping_pickup == $shipping_method_pickup) {
            $fields_pickup['billing'][$field_pickup]['required'] = false;
            $fields_pickup['billing'][$field_pickup]['class'][] = 'hide_pickup';
        }
        $fields_pickup['billing'][$field_pickup]['class'][] = 'billing-dynamic_pickup';
    }
    return $fields_pickup;
}
// Local Pickup - hide fields
add_action( 'wp_head', 'local_pickup_fields', 999 );
function local_pickup_fields() {
    if (is_checkout()) :
    ?>
    <style>
        .hide_pickup {display: none!important;}
    </style>
    <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ) {
            if ( typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined' ) {
                return false;
            }

            $(document).on( 'change', '#shipping_method input[type="radio"]', function() {
                // change flat_rate:3 accordingly
                $('.billing-dynamic_pickup').toggleClass('hide_pickup', this.value == 'flat_rate:3');
            });

            $( document ).on('updated_checkout', function(event) {  
                // change flat_rate:3 accordingly
                $('.billing-dynamic_pickup').toggleClass('hide_pickup', $('.shipping_method:checked').val() == 'flat_rate:3');
            });

        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! I tried using it but it didn't work. I didn't know the updated_checkout was a thing so i looked for another way to use that trigger and it worked! I'm leaving the new code below. thanks a lot!